# Trapezoidal Integration in C

Tags: c

I am trying to compute the integral of the function f(x)=(1-x^2)^(1/2) from x=0 to x=1. The answer should be approximately pi/4. I am currently getting 2.

My current implementation of the trapezoidal rule is the following:

[image]

```
double
def_integral(double *f, double *x, int n)
{
  double F;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    F += 0.5 * ( x[i+1] - x[i] ) * ( f[i] + f[i+1] );
  }
  return F;
}
```

I'm creating N divisions to approximate the area under the curve between x_1=0 and x_N=1 by looping through i to N with x_i = i / N.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int N = 1000;
  double f_x[N];
  double x[N];

  for (int i = 0 ; i <= N ; i++) {
    double x = i * 1. / N;
    f_x[i] = sqrt(1. - pow(x, 2.));
    //printf("%.2f %.5f\n", x, f_x[i]); //uncomment if you wanna see function values
  }

  double F_x = def_integral(f_x, x, N);

  printf("The integral is %g\n", F_x);
}
```

The result of 2 that I am currently getting should be dependent on the number of N division, however, no matter if I make N=10000 or N=100, I still get 2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That loop in `main()` goes out of bounds of `f_x`... And you never initialize your `x` array before trying to use it. (Plus you have an array and scalar variable both named `x` which is confusing). Also out of bounds array accesses in `def_integral()`...

Comment: You should initialize `double F` to zero.

Comment: Compiling with a healthy set of warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang) will help with some of your problems; also compiling with `-fsanitize=address` or running through valgrind might help with others.

Comment: Yes @user58697! Your answer in combination with @LocTran 's answer solved the issue, I am now getting the correct answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Side note: `(1. - pow(x, 2.)` is not as numerically stable nor precise as `(1.0 - x)*(1.0 + x)`.

Comment: @chux brilliant! I will make this change. Does the 0 in "1.0" matter? Or is it numerically the same as "1."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this `for` loop, you forgot updatin array `x` as well.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= N ; i++) {
    double x = i * 1. / N;
    f_x[i] = sqrt(1. - pow(x, 2.));
    //printf("%.2f %.5f\n", x, f_x[i]); //uncomment if you wanna see function values
}
```

So, `for` loop should be replaced by

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= N ; i++) {
    double xi = i * 1. / N;
    x[i] = xi;
    f_x[i] = sqrt(1. - pow(xi , 2.));
    //printf("%.2f %.5f\n", x, f_x[i]); //uncomment if you wanna see function values
}
```

Comment: Okay this definitely caused some things to change. In this state, I get `The integral is 2.7851` which is still not quite right. However, if I simply uncomment the `printf` function which prints the functions values, I get the correct answer of 0.785. What is happening here?

Comment: This code prints the good result on my computer whithout uncommenting printf function. But, I think I am a lucky man. Look at the comments of Shawn in the question. If you declare an array : `arr[N]`, then the indices go from 0 to N-1 and in the for loop you go from 0 to N. If you want N intervals, the array size must be N+1 because the function must be calculated N+1 times. (For example  N=4 : F(0)<->F(1)<->F(2)<->F(3) )

Answer (score 1):

In your main code, you call `def_integral` with a double (`x`) and in the function an array of x (`double * x`) is expected. Perhaps (it is what I suppose), the problem comes from the fact you formula needs *x(i+1)-x(i)* but you use a constant step. Indeed, x(i+1)-x(i)=step_x is constant so you do not need each x(i) but only value : 1./N
Other remark, with a constant step, your formula could be simplified to : 
F_x=step_x* **(** 0.5*f_x(x0)+ f_x(x1)+...+f_x(xn-1)+ 0.5*f_x(xn) **)** . It helps to simplify the code and to write a better efficient one.
Everything is commented in the code above. I hope it could help you. 
Best regards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double
def_integral(double *f, double step_x, int n)
{
  double F;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    F += 0.5 * ( step_x ) * ( f[i] + f[i+1] );
  }
  return F;
}

int main()
{
  int N = 1001; // 1001 abscissas means 1000 intervalls (see comment on array size and indices)
  double f_x[N]; // not needed for the simplified algorithm
  double step_x = 1. / N; // x(i+1)-x(i) is constant

  for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) { // Note : i<N and not i<=N
    double xi = i * step_x; // abscissa calculation
    f_x[i] = sqrt((1. - xi )*(1. + xi )); // cf chux comment
  }

  double F_x = def_integral(f_x, step_x, N);
  printf("The integral is %.10g\n", F_x);

// simplified algorithm
// F_x=step_x*( 0.5*f_x(x0)+f_x(x1)+...+f_x(xn-1)+0.5f_x(xn) )
  double xi;
  xi=0; // x(0)
  F_x=0.5*sqrt((1. - xi )*(1. + xi ));
  for (int i=1 ; i<=N-1 ; i++) {
    xi=step_x*i;
    F_x+=sqrt((1. - xi )*(1. + xi ));
  }
  xi=step_x*N;
  F_x+=0.5*sqrt((1. - xi )*(1. + xi ));
  F_x=step_x*F_x;
  printf("The integral is %.10g\n", F_x);

}
```

Comment: May I suggest a more organized (IMHO) [approach](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7O8SfHkyLNwtsNTx) ?

Comment: @Bob. I agree it is much more organized.